# Pass Type with condition to generic method

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Hi I have two generic methods like below:

```
public class MethodA<Type>() where Type : class
{
     Debug.Log("MethodA is called");
}
public class MethodB<Type>()
{
     if(typeof(Type).IsClass)
         MethodA<Type>();
}
```

`MethodA` is a generic method that has constraint only class type are accepted, `MethodB` on the other hand does not have any restriction.

I want to call `MethodA` from `MethodB` is that generic `Type` is class type. however it will show error  and tell me I cannot ensure that the `Type` that I put in is a class type even though I already check it one line earlier.

What should I do?

Comment: The error you get is 'Type must be a reference type'. Because you have the where Type : class on MethodA you need to hand it a class type. Checking it before you call does not change the fact that the Type is not a reference type. So you need to specify where Type : class on MethodB too, to be able to call MethodA with it. B.t.w. the syntax is wrong 'public class MethodA()' is invalid. I think you mean 'public void MethodA()'

Comment: `if(typeof(Type).IsClass)` is not statically verifiable by the compiler, and won't help it to ensure that `Type` is actually a reference type, you must us `where Type : class`

Comment: thank you for both of your reply! yet my MethodB can also be called and enter non-class type into it. Is there a way to let the compiler know that I'm calling MethodA within the correct condition?